# RX Java RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java

I'm not familiar with rx java. Trying to use it with recycleview. For some reason my code is not working Here is my code.

Fragment with recycle view

```
 public class CheeseListFragment extends Fragment {
        private final CompositeSubscription subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
        private  PublishSubject<String> timespanSubject;
        private final Func1<String, Observable<LiveInfo>> trendingSearch =
                new Func1<String, Observable<LiveInfo>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<LiveInfo> call(String s) {
                        RadioLiveInfoObservableService radioLiveInfoObservableService=ApiProvider.getInstance().getRadioObserverInfo();
                        return radioLiveInfoObservableService.radioInfo(Type.INTERVAL)
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .doOnError(trendingError)
                                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<LiveInfo>empty());
                    }
                };

        private final Action1<Throwable> trendingError = new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to get trending repositories");
            }
        };

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            timespanSubject = PublishSubject.create();
            final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_cheese_list, container, false);    
            setupRecyclerView(rv);

            subscriptions.add(timespanSubject
                    .flatMap(trendingSearch)
                    .map(SearchResultToRepositoryList.instance())
                    .subscribe(adapter));
            return rv;
        }

            private SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

        private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
             adapter=new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.CurrentShowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCurrentShowClick(Current currentShow) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CApplication.getAppContext(), CheeseDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CheeseDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, currentShow.getName());

                    CApplication.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"data changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        private List<String> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
            Random random = new Random();
            while (list.size() < amount) {
                list.add(array[random.nextInt(array.length)]);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter
                extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Action1<List<Current>> {
            private List<Current> currentShows = Collections.emptyList();

            public interface CurrentShowClickListener {
                void onCurrentShowClick(Current currentShow);
            }

            private final CurrentShowClickListener currentShowClickListener;

            private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
            private int mBackground;

            @Override
            public void call(List<Current> currentShows) {
                this.currentShows = currentShows;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,CurrentShowClickListener currentShowClickListener) {
                context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
                mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
                this.currentShowClickListener = currentShowClickListener;
            }

            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                ListItemView view = (ListItemView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                viewHolder.bindTo(currentShows.get(i));
            }

            @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override public int getItemCount() {
                return currentShows.size();
            }

            public final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public final ListItemView itemView;
                private Current currentShow;

                public ViewHolder(ListItemView itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    this.itemView = itemView;
                    this.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                            currentShowClickListener.onCurrentShowClick(currentShow);
                        }
                    });
                }

                public void bindTo(Current currentShow) {
                    this.currentShow = currentShow;
                    itemView.bindTo(currentShow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

SearchToResultRepositoryList

```
public final class SearchResultToRepositoryList implements Func1<LiveInfo, List<Current>> {
  private static volatile SearchResultToRepositoryList instance;

  public static SearchResultToRepositoryList instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SearchResultToRepositoryList();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  @Override public List<Current> call(LiveInfo repositoriesResponse) {
    List<Current> currents=new ArrayList<>();
    currents.add(repositoriesResponse.getCurrent());
    return currents;
  }
}
```

REST

```
public interface RadioLiveInfoObservableService {

    @GET("/api/live-info/")
    Observable<LiveInfo> radioInfo(
            @Query("type") Type type);
}
```

It's just doing nothing. I tried to debug it trendingSearch.call is not called at all.

I can make it work only this way. But still i want to know how to it with subscription

```
RadioLiveInfoObservableService radioLiveInfoObservableService=ApiProvider.getInstance().getRadioObserverInfo();
radioLiveInfoObservableService.commits(Type.INTERVAL)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError(trendingError)
        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<LiveInfo>empty()).subscribe(new Action1<LiveInfo>() {
    @Override
    public void call(LiveInfo liveInfo) {
        List<Current> currents=new ArrayList<Current>();
        currents.add(liveInfo.getCurrent());
        adapter.currentShows=currents;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code to digest looking for errors, but off the top of my head nothing will happen until `timeSpanSubject.onNext()` is called. I don't see this called anywhere but maybe there is some missing code you are not showing.

If there is no missing code that calls `timeSpanSubject.onNext()`, then you could use either a `BehaviorSubject` which will emit an item when first subscribed to or another Observable such as [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) or [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) depending on what you are trying to do. `timer` would subscribe to your `trendingSearch` Observable a single time whereas using an `interval` would subscribe multiple times.

Comment: Sir, can you show me how to use it with interval? i need to repeat this call everytime.

Comment: Ok. it worked. I called onNext after subscription. Now can you show brief example with interval. Also if I turn off the internet and turn on it again it stops working

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza- To use an interval replace `timeSpanSubject` with the desired interval Observable. For example, the following will execute trendingSearch every 10 seconds
        subscriptions.add(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .flatMap(trendingSearch)
                    .map(SearchResultToRepositoryList.instance())
                    .subscribe(adapter));

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza - When you turn off the internet, the `trendingSearch` Observable is getting an error. It does look like your `onErrorResumeNext()` should handle this by returning an empty list. Then, the next time the `interval` fires when the internet is back on, `trendingSearch` should execute again. The only way it would stop is if the error is occurring somewhere other than `trendingSearch`. For example, if `.map(SearchResultToRepositoryList.instance())` does not handle the empty list properly and is throwing an error.

Comment: thanks a lot. in future i think i will learn this rx java stuff